# Unhandled Rejection error when running ng test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Running ng test opens a Chromium browser with localhost:9876 in a tab. Clicking on this browser immediately crashes it. The browser closes and the ng test process stops with the message `ERROR [karma-server]: UnhandledRejection`.

The ng test keeps running if I never click on the Chromium browser or shift focus to it intentionally.

(i) I can still see which tests are passing and failing in the terminal.

(ii) I can still see the coverage percentage since I've set `angular.json >  projects > <projectname> > architect > test > codeCoverage` as true.

(iii) I can still see the what lines of the code are covered in the `coverage > index.html`.

No. (i) is quite inconvenient which is why I'm asking this question.

What I've tried so far:

- Opening localhost:9876 in another browser by typing in that URL. The ng test process crashes and shows the Unhandled Rejection error when I click on the Debug button on the webpage.
- Running ng test in elevated PowerShell. Didn't make a difference.

Versions:

- Chromium Version 78.0.3882.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit) which comes
  with the puppeteer installation.
- Karma v4.4.1
- Jasmine 3.5.0
- Angular CLI 8.3.29
- Angular 8.2.14
- Node 16.14.2
- OS: Windows 10